# Call COM Add-In Function in VBA

Tags: excel, vba, microsoft-dynamics, excel-addins, microsoft-dynamics-nav

I want to call the "Refresh" function of the Microsoft Dynamics NAV Excel Add-in which has a button on the ribbon using VBA.
[image]

I tried recording a macro when clicking the button but the code does not work and throws a runtime error due to the `Selection.AutoFilter` lines.
[image]

```vb
Sub Macro1()
'
' Macro1 Macro
'

'
    ActiveWorkbook.Names("ConnectionInfo").Delete
    ActiveWorkbook.Names.Add Name:="ConnectionInfo", RefersToR1C1:= _
        "='Sales Orders'!R1C1:R1C16"
    ActiveWorkbook.Names("ObjectInfo").Delete
    ActiveWorkbook.Names.Add Name:="ObjectInfo", RefersToR1C1:= _
        "='Sales Orders'!R2C1:R2C16"
    ActiveWorkbook.Names("ConnectionInfo").Delete
    ActiveWorkbook.Names.Add Name:="ConnectionInfo", RefersToR1C1:= _
        "='Sales Orders'!R1C1:R1C16"
    ActiveWorkbook.Names("ObjectInfo").Delete
    ActiveWorkbook.Names.Add Name:="ObjectInfo", RefersToR1C1:= _
        "='Sales Orders'!R2C1:R2C16"
    With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sales Orders").ListObjects("NavDataRegion"). _
        Sort
        .Header = xlYes
        .MatchCase = False
        .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
        .SortMethod = xlPinYin
        .Apply
    End With
Selection.AutoFilter
Selection.AutoFilter
End Sub
```

The macro names the ranges in the data containing the connection address and NAV list name, but doesn't do anything with them.

It is a VSTO COM add-in and as far as I know does not show up in:

VBA References
[image]

Add-ins
[image]

or object browser
[image]

I ran this code:

```vb
Sub comDATA()
    Dim oCAI As COMAddIn
    For Each oCAI In Application.COMAddIns
        Debug.Print oCAI.Description & vbTab & oCAI.progID
    Next oCAI
End Sub
```

and found the ProgID is [Microsoft.Dynamics.NAV.ExcelAddin](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f9v7f.png), but I don't know the Refresh button's function name or how to execute it.

Comment: I found an old thread about this that remains unanswered for years. They talk about using `SendKeys` to press the buttons to cause the refresh. I don't recommend doing that. Bad things will happen. https://community.dynamics.com/ax/f/microsoft-dynamics-ax-forum/87586/executing-dynamics-ax-add-in-commands-from-macro-vba-code

Comment: Thanks for the link. I have also seen sendkeys and UIAutomation for keyboard shortcut and even clicking emulation, but definitely don't to implement such a roundabout solution. I feel I am missing something simple but can't seem to find anything on Google.

Comment: Just because something should exist doesn't mean it does. I can't find the API documentation for this Add-in either. Your best bet would be to get a handle on the object with something like `Set NAVObject = CreateObject("Microsoft.Dynamics.NAV.ExcelAddin")` and then explore the `NAVObject` in your locals window during a debug session.

Comment: Note: It may not export any useful public methods.

Answer (score 0):

Try to refresh the `ListObject` itself.

```
With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sales Orders")
    .ListObjects("NavDataRegion").Refresh
End With
```

Comment: WARNING: This is untested air code. I don't have Microsoft Dynamics NAV Excel Add-in and I cannot test.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I get an error: "Application-defined or object-defined error" when trying to run the code, so I guess the add-in has a different process to refresh the data.